# Creating a Python dictionary from other nested list containing dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

**I have this list that contains dictionaries as its element**

```
dict_1 = [{'id': '0eb7df70-f319-4562-ab2a-9e641e978b3b', 'first_name': 'Rahx', 'surname': 'Smith ', 'devices': {'os': 'Apple iPhone', 'mac_address': 'f4:af:e7:b7:ab:22', 'manufacturer': 'Apple'}, 'lat': 54.33166199876629, 'lng': -6.277842272724769, 'seenTime': 1582814754000},
{'id': 'a0bb8d38-0d27-4d7f-acc0-1e850a706b6c', 'first_name': 'Lucy', 'surname': 'Pye', 'devices': {'os': 'Apple iPhone', 'mac_address': 'f8:87:f1:72:4c:4d', 'manufacturer': 'Apple'}, 'lat': 54.33166199876629, 'lng': -6.277842272724769, 'seenTime': 1582814754000}, 
{'id': '0eb7df70-f319-4562-ab2a-9e641e978b3b', 'first_name': 'xyx', 'surname': 'dcsdd', 'devices': {'os': 'NOKIA Phone', 'mac_address': '78:28:ca:a8:56:b9', 'manufacturer': 'NOKIA'}, 'lat': 54.33166199876629, 'lng': -6.277842272724769, 'seenTime': 1582814754000}, 
{'id': 'a0bb8d38-0d27-4d7f-acc0-1e850a706b6c', 'first_name': 'ddwdw', 'surname': 'sdsds', 'devices': {'os': 'MI Phone', 'mac_address': 'dc:08:0f:3f:57:0c', 'manufacturer': 'MI'}, 'lat': 54.33218267030654, 'lng': -6.27796001203896, 'seenTime': 1582814693000}]
```

**and I want output like this from dict_1 variable**

```
{
  "f77df8c2-b19d-4341-9021-7beab4b9ebcd":{
      "first_name":"anonymous",
      "surname":"anonymous",
      "lat":57.14913102,
      "lng":-2.09987143,
      "devices": {'os': 'MI Phone', 'mac_address': 'dc:08:0f:3f:57:0c', 'manufacturer': 'MI'},
      "seenTime": 1582814693000
  },
  "7beab4b9ebcd-b19d-9021-f77df8c2-4341":{
  etc.
  },
  etc.
}
```

help me to know what should I do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
dict_1 = {x.pop('id'): x for x in dict_1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could do the job :

```
dict_2 = {}
for d in dict_1 :
   id = d.pop('id')
   dict_2[id] = d
```